# Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 disable users list

Tags: 22.04, users, gdm, sssd, ubuntu-budgie

I've just installed the pretty Budgie 22.04 on my workstation.

Users list comes from SSSD Ldap integration, but only local users show in login screen.

I've tried various things to hide the users list (and have to type username on login screen)

/etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[greeter]
Include=some_ldap_user
```

/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-login-[org/gnome/login-screen]

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
disable-user-list=true
```

... then "dconf update"

But nothing helps...

Comment: Do you also want, say, network users to show up? If not, try and use Ly as your display manager. It requires username & pw input on every login, which might help mitigate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why the other day I made the false assertion that the display manager was mdm... It's of course lightdm
Probleme is fixed with "greeter-hide-users" param in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50_budgie-desktop.conf :

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=budgie-desktop
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
```